# How to add a label to the timezone dropdown list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display "Organization's timezone" label to the following input in my rails engine

The code which i have used is :

```
    f.time_zone_select :timezone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones , :label "Organization "
```

but i'm getting an error....How this should be corrected

Comment: What is the error? Update it in the question.

Comment: There's no error ,But the label is not displaying

Comment: @TharinduThathsarana you said _"but i'm getting an error"_ in your question (and the above code would in fact result in an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  f.input :timezone, as: :time_zone, label: "Organization's timezone"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the key `:label` to the data `"Organization"`, so the correct format is...

```
 f.time_zone_select :timezone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones , :label => "Organization"
```

or more succinctly

```
 f.time_zone_select :timezone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones , label: "Organization"
```

Comment: Works for me.  I put on a test view `<%= f.time_zone_select(:timezone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, label: 'Organization') %>` and it displayed correctly, showed the time zone pull downs, showed the label `Organization`.  Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: I'm not getting error but it displays the dropdown list without the label.I have used this on a rails engine.Can it be the reason for this?

Comment: Is there any other method to do the same thing?